# Validation when check box is checked using jQuery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate input fields when a check box is checked, otherwise the input field don't validate when submit a form.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" name="type1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="name1" class="validate[funcCall[checkHELLO]]" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" class="validate[funcCall[checkHELLO]]" />
    <input type="text" name="name3" class="validate[funcCall[checkHELLO]]" />
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

```js
function checkHELLO() {
  if ($("type1").is(':checked')) {

  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#field-validations

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: i need to validate those input box when type 1 checkbox is cheched

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly.

Comment: i using jquery validation engine using single form with different fields. for example 3 check box and 9 input text box. if first check box is checked then validate first three input box need to validate, if 2nd check box is checked then need to validate next three input field similarly third, if i check box 2 only selected means then validate second three input box only validate and submit a form

Comment: jquery validation engine library link for that link

Comment: you just need to check checkbox value by `$("input[name=type1]").is(':checked')` instead of `$("type1").is(':checked')` cause it means nothing